# I cant get my textures in final rendered image

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image: This is the final render which doesnt show metallic texture of handle, only the glow]Hi i am a noob to blender. I was trying this tutorial on youtube on creating a sword and i cant seem to get my textures appear in final render. Everything shows up fine in rendered view and material view as well.I tried both cycles and evee rendering engine. I am attaching link to my file below.Please help me..

edit:
i reattached the file with textures and all. Sorry for the huge filesize its probably because of huge soundtrack..
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=192dcpdrvthIZNADe6xS0h-ONtXrngi7W)

Comment: [edit] your question and upload your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). Cannot replicate the issue, textures show up just fine. Please add some images to compare your viewport/render.

Comment: I did edit my question and uploaded rendered image as well.thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. I just simply added a hdri background image and it worked. For anyone else having the same problem, try googling how to add hdri background in blender and you will get the answer. Thanks  to everyone who answered..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't UV unwrap the mesh. Select the object, in edit menu and Unwrap it by clicking "U" and you can either do it manually or select the Smart UV to unwrap.

Check this video to understand it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM

If you actually did it but still it isn't showing, then you need to share the blend file along with the textures packed in it so that others can view it(You actually shared only the blend file, not textures).

This might help you: https://help.augment.com/en/articles/2510164-blender-how-to-export-your-3d-models

Comment: I did reattach the file.please do check the file and tell me what i am doing wrong and sorry for the huge filesize

Comment: In that case, can you please remove the audio file and send it, bcz its too huge to download